# How to return multi-dimensional array from controller to ajax success?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ajaxq

I am calling controller POST method via jquery ajax. Controller method is returning 2D array to ajax.
I am able to successfully get array in ajax success but it becomes 1D array instead I want it to be 2D array or whatever dimensional array I have sent from controller method.

Here is my controller method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult MultiDArrayToView(string s)
        {
            string[,] table = new string[2, 2];
            table[0, 0] = "1";
            table[0, 1] = "2";
            table[1,0] = "3";
            table[1,1] = "4";
            var response = new { table = table};
            return Json(response);

        }
```

Here is my View code:

```
<body>
    <div> 
        <form action="/Home/MultiDArrayToView" method="post" id="form">
            <input name="s" required/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
                var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
                var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
                var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
                $.ajax({
                    url: post_url,
                    type: request_method,
                    data: form_data,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (value) {
                        //here I am getting array from controller method in 'value' but as a 1D array instead I want multidimensional array
                        debugger;
                    }
                });


            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you verify that the json response from your POST Action is indeed constructed as a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: Yes it is being constructed as 2D array.

Comment: Well then your question is about javascript and parsing a two dimensional array and has nothing really to do with your back-end itself.

Comment: Okay, so any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Well I would rather edit the question or create a totally new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the matrix:
 `string[,] table = new string[2, 2];`

Use a jagged array 
`string[][] table = new string[2][2];`

This will allow the json serializer to effectively do the conversion.